# Gradient based optimization involving a black box function where gradients (not the objective) are approximated using a surrogate model

Tags: optimization

Can we use gradients of surrogates of a black box function and the actual function evaluation for optimization involving an expensive black box simulation? Is there any merits to it?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.   Are you saying that you're using values from the black box model to estimate derivatives of the objective and then fitting a surrogate model to estimate gradients?  Normally you fit the surrogate model to the function values and then used the (smoothed) derivatives of the surrogate model.

Comment: Okay let me explain a little. I want to use the actual function values from the simulation but only want to use the gradients from a surrogate model. The surrogate model is fitted for the input and output pairs of the simulation.

Comment: Using gradients that are inconsistent with the objective value can cause most optimization algorithms to fail to converge.  This is not a concern if you're optimizing a surrogate model using the surrogate's function values and gradients.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what quasi-Newton methods do? Compute approximations of the Hessian matrix?

Comment: I think what you're describing is called multifidelity optimization. I've seen it multiple times in my field of aerodynamics where multiple levels of model fidelity are available and the high-fidelity models have a large computational cost. Here are some similar articles:
https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/mechanicaldesign/article/143/8/081702/1095444/Comparing-Filtering-Multifidelity-Optimization
https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/1.J051125